# Building trackable links using PHP and a MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have an email list and a personalized PDF associated with each email (a one-to-one relationship). I also have a server that hosts the PDFs. I want to send each person their personalized PDF using a link to the file on my server. When I send a person that link, I want to to track whether they have downloaded the file.

This [download.php script](https://gist.github.com/dangrossman/f59bd986c7cd0eb9633c) (full code below) was recommended to as I can include my links as `http://yourdomain.com/download.php?email={!email}` so that when they are clicked, the script will write to a MySQL database to track which email address clicked the link and then serve the file.

**The download.php script**

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
mysql_select_db('dbname');

$sql = "INSERT INTO downloads (email) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']) . "')";
mysql_query($sql);

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile("/path/to/thefile.pdf");

?>
```

My issue is that the last line of the code `readfile("/path/to/thefile.pdf");` looks as if it needs to be written such that it contains the path to a single file, which will not work for my purposes. Am I reading the code correctly and if so, is there a way to modify it for my purposes?

Comment: have you heard of PDO?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly. You have to paste the path to your PDF on the server. e.g. http://www.youdomain.com/pdfs/october.pdf

Avoid mysql functions and use PDO always.

This is how you do it in PDO

```
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dbname", $username, $password);

$user_mail = $_GET['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO downloads (email) VALUES (:emailVal)";
$statement = $con_db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array(':emailVal'=> $user_mail));

header("Content-type: application/pdf");
readfile("/path/to/thefile.pdf"); //paste to your PDF on your server
```

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. I cannot paste the path because every PDF has a different path. Also, I am not sure what PDO is but I am sure I could figure it out.

Comment: why not use a single path with different file names? That way it's much convenient to deal with.

Comment: That is what I want to do. But in the example, the end is thefile.pdf, which is the path for a single file.

Comment: try something like this `readfile("/standard/Path/to/".thefile.pdf);` . standard path within quotes concatinated by the dynamic filename. you can assign a varable name to the file name.

Comment: Does the variable name go in the link? Could you possibly update your answer to reflect this solution?

Comment: The info you've given is not sufficient to fully understand what and how you're doing this. Where are you creating the file name?

Comment: I manually create a file and name it using a convention I have created whereby the file is called Analysis[CompanyName].pdf.  I then manually upload a group of these files to a server so that I have a group of file on the server such as AnalysisCompanyName1.pdf, AnalysisCompanyName2.pdf, etc.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please elaborate?